# Reason for third condition in definition of Well-posed Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

From the definition (due to Hadamard) of well-posed problem we know there are three conditions

```
          (1) existence of solution;
          (2) uniqueness of solution;
          (3) solution's behavior must change continuously with initial
              conditions.
```

Now first two conditions are logically meaningful to me but I can't understand why do we need third condition?

Answer (score 0):

The third condition just means that small causes (i.e. small changes in the initial condition) produce small effects (i.e. small changes in the solution.) This is clearly desirable in any equation describing a physical process.